# Where is the JSON format for a tree & grid data query documented?

Tags: kendo-ui

The code in [the remote data grid example](http://demos.kendoui.com/web/grid/remote-data.html) has:

```
       dataSource: {
            type: "odata",
            transport: {
                read: "http://demos.kendoui.com/service/Northwind.svc/Orders"
            },
```

The data comes back (JSON but writing as XML cause it's easier) as "d/__count, d/results[]. results is [0]/Order_Details/OrderID, etc.

While this all works, I have a bunch of questions about this:

1. Where is this documented?
2. Are there other values that can be returned? I want to return a boolean of success/failure and a string with an error message on failure.
3. Can the names/structure of what's returned be changed?
4. How does it work to go to Order_Details.OrderID to get OrderID? What if there was also an Employee.OrderID (Employee complex property is also returned)? Does it grab the first that matches? Can that be overridden? Will it go to any depth?
5. What's the meaning of the inlinecount=allpages in the request URI?

And similar questions for [the tree control](http://demos.kendoui.com/web/treeview/remote-data.html).

1. Above questions 1, 2, 3.
2. How does it know to pass EmployeeID as a value when requesting the sub-nodes of a node.

Comment: Have you tried asking on the telerik forums?

Comment: This is the forum Telerik points to.

Answer (score 1):

The format you are looking at is [OData](http://odata.org) (this is why the data source type option is set to "odata"). Some of the Kendo UI sample services return OData and others return JSONP (JSON with Padding, needed for Cross-domain requests).

You can bind the TreeView and Grid to any service which returns JSON in any format. You need to properly configure the data source so it knows which field from the JSON response contains your data items. Check the data source [schema.data](http://docs.kendoui.com/api/framework/datasource#configuration-schema.data) documentation.

For example if your service "/api/service" returns the following JSON:

```
{
   items: [
      { foo: "foo" },
      { foo: "bar" }
   ],
   count: 2
}
```

You need to configure the Kendo DataSource like this:

```
dataSource: {
    transport: {
       read: {
          url: "/api/service",
          dataType: "json"
       }
    },
    schema: {
       data: "items", /* the items field contains the data items */
       total: "count", /* optional, specifies the field which contains the total number of items in case your service supports paging */
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi. Thank you - that's part of what I was looking for. How do I return an error? schema.errors appears to be for an error with the connection. What if my REST server determines the request is incorrect and wants to return that the request failed and an error message? Thanks